# How to GET variable as instance from PHP after POST by flash actionscript

Tags: php, actionscript-3, post, get

Hi I'm working on actionscript, saving a raw image from camera then POST with save.php then
I want save.php echo back the variable which is a file name that have just generated by save.php to actionscript
see this line: 
  var urlParameter:String = "images/test_01.php?img=" + "myfileURL";
  navigateToURL(new URLRequest(urlParameter), "_blank");

Thanks in advance

this is AS3 code

```
function onSaveJPG(e:Event):void{
    var myEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    var byteArray:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

    var saveJPG:URLRequest = new URLRequest("save.php");
    saveJPG.requestHeaders.push(header);
    saveJPG.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    saveJPG.data = byteArray;

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);
    urlLoader.load(saveJPG);

    function sendComplete(event:Event):void{
        warn.visible = true;
        addChild(warn);
        warn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, warnDown);
        warn.buttonMode = true;  
    } 


    function warnDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
        var urlParameter:String = "images/test_01.php?img=" + "myfileURL";
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(urlParameter), "_blank");
        //  navigateToURL(new URLRequest("images/"), "_blank"); 
        //  +saveJPG:URLRequest 
        // navigateToURL(new URLRequest("images/test_01.php?img=+saveJPG:URLRequest"), "_blank");
        warn.visible = false;
    }

} // move onSave JPG
} close to here instead of after sendComplete
```

warn.visible = false;

this is save.php

```
<?php
```

if(isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
 $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
 $img = $*GET["img"];
 $filename = "images/poza*". mktime(). ".jpg";
 file_put_contents($filename, $jpg);

echo "thisPic=" . $filename;
 // echo $filename;

} else{
 echo "Encoded JPEG information not received.";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are just using `mktime()` for the file name, and `images/poza` is hard coded. You can post the file name along the jpeg data from flash, and when `onSaveJPG` is called you simply display the file name to the user.

Below is example of how you can send file_name.

```
var JPGFileName = YOUR TIME FUNCTION
var saveJPG:URLRequest = new URLRequest("save.php?file_name=" + JPGFileName);
saveJPG.requestHeaders.push(header); 
saveJPG.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; saveJPG.data = byteArray;
```